# How to select column names by data type

Tags: sql-server

How would I get the names of all the columns in a table that are of a specific type such as datetime?

Even better -- How can I do the same thing but with multiple tables joined together and then list the column name along with the table it comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I get the names of all the columns in a table that are of a specific type such as datetime?

(output as `schema_name | table_name | column_name | data_type`):

```
SELECT Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) as [SCHEMA_NAME]
    ,object_NAME(c.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME
    ,c.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
    ,t.NAME AS DATA_TYPE
    -- add / remove columns as per need
    --,c.max_length AS MAX_LENGTH
FROM sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) <> 'sys' -- not sys schema
    -- filters 
        and t.name = 'Datetime'
    --  and object_NAME(c.object_id) = 'someTableName'
```

Comment: Very nice query! :)

Answer (score 7):

Query `sys.columns` and `sys.types` like this:

```
select object_name(c.object_id) TableName, * 
FROM sys.columns c
join sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where t.name = 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. The documentation says that `TABLE_SCHEMA` is not reliable for objects, but I assume it works for tables and columns:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = ?
```

Reference:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

Comment: Please read - [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) from Aaron's blog. It will convince you not to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views.

Comment: I don't know sql server all that well, and I'm pretty sure @Aaron Bertrand  has valid arguments against INFORMATION_SCHEMA. In an ideal world we could use INFORMATION_SCHEMA in the same way in all DBMS that supports them, but unfortunately it is often necessary to retrieve implementation specific details from the DBMS. Though, I don't see any problems using  INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the OP's question.

Comment: For consistency *within SQL Server* - often more important than consistency *across all possible, however unlikely, DBMS platforms*.

Answer (score 1):

For a given table...

```
SELECT sc.name AS column_name, t.name AS data_type, t.max_length, t.[precision], t.scale
FROM sys.columns sc
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON sc.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE sc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person')
ORDER BY sc.column_id
```

This will give you them in the order they are listed in the table. By using user_type you also cover for the possibility of user created data types. The last 3 fields are needed for data types that take extra parameters, eg VARCHAR(200), NUMERIC(12,3). If you see a -1 in the max_length field, then it's probably something like VARCHAR(MAX) or XML.

For multiple tables, it's tricky. You could create a table from your tables (maybe with a SELECT TOP(0) so as to not bother copying the data) and then plug it into the above. However if you have fields with the same name in those tables, then your table will not create. Remember to drop your table afterwards. You could do a temp table but they are trickier to find the object_id for.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way:

```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns WHERE 
     table_name = 'MYTABLE' AND DATA_TYPE = 'DATE'


   SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM user_tab_columns 
     WHERE  DATA_TYPE = 'DATE'
```

Comment: This is for SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't pay attention on the tag. This is for Oracle.